# Type mismatch: inferred type is BluetoothDevice? but BluetoothDevice was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, parcelable, parcel

I know that this is a very simple error but I can't quite comprehend the nuances of kotlin enough to solve it just yet.

I'm getting the error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is BluetoothDevice? but BluetoothDevice was expected

When trying to pass a `BluetoothDevice` in as parcelable

```
class ScanDevice(var device: BluetoothDevice, var rssi: Int): Parcelable {
   ...
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readParcelable(BluetoothDevice::class.java.classLoader), <--- here
        parcel.readInt()
    )
    ...
```

It's technically just a warning and not actually an error but I'm not sure what is happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for `Parcel.readerParcelable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel#readParcelable(java.lang.ClassLoader)) says:

> Returns the newly created `Parcelable`, or `null` if a null object has been written.

This means that, if we were living in Kotlin world, the return type of `Parcel.readParcelable()` would be `T?` and not `T` (i.e. it would be nullable).

Since you are in control of the writing, you *know* that it won't return null. That means that you're safe to convert the result to a non-nullable type by using the `!!` operator:

```
parcel.readParcelable(BluetoothDevice::class.java.classLoader)!!
```

Comment: Ask an easy question and you get an easy answer. I'll make it harder next time! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Parcel.readParcelable` is nullable. If the `Parcel` had previously had a null value written to it at that position, null would be returned. In your case, if you can guarantee that you are never writing null to the `Parcel`, you can simply assert that the value is not null:

```
constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
    parcel.readParcelable(BluetoothDevice::class.java.classLoader)!!,
    parcel.readInt()
)
```

This would crash at runtime if a null value were written to the `Parcel`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using !! it would probably be better to to perform a null safe call like this.

```
parcel?.let{
    it.readParcelable(BluetoothDevice::class.java.classLoader) 
    it.readInt()
}
```

This only executes the code when parcel is not null. Only use `!!` when you are 100% sure that variable/object is not null.

Comment: I like that too